# Android Studio-Gradle issue-.bin file error

Tags: android, android-studio

i see "Error:C:\Documents and Settings\Student.gradle\daemon\2.8\registry.bin (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)" in android studio...how to solve it...

Comment: More info and take screenshot the error

Comment: can not refresh the project.....

Answer (score 0):

Test this method .
You use a proxy like freegate 
Run cmd and goto to main folder project .
And run this code `gradlew -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8580`
proxyPort=Your used proxy

Comment: imgButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()){
            public void onClick(View V){
                StartActivity(new intent(this,OptionsActivity.class));
            }

        } ........   but can't run.....

Comment: This is a new questions . You commit and finsh the questions and create new questions .